# hide listview item in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datagridviewcolumn

hi i have listview how i can hide Id column? this is my listview xaml:

```
<ListView FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="Single" Name="dgv" Margin="12,0,10,-81">
     <ListView.View>
              <GridView>
                       <GridViewColumn Header="آموزشگاه"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                       <GridViewColumn Header="مدیر"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Admin}" />
                       <GridViewColumn Header="پایه"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Base}" />
                       <GridViewColumn Header="سال تحصیلی"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Year}" />
                       <GridViewColumn Header="Id"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
              </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Setting Width to 0 is a solution for you?

Comment: @dsdel tnx it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accepted solution/workaround in this case is setting the Width to 0.